# How to upload multiple images and store their name in database with laravel 5.1?

Tags: image, laravel, upload

I have created a form for users can upload multiple images,and move uploaded images to 'Upload' folder and store their names in database. This is my code

```
public function multiple_upload() {
    $multiupload = new Multiupload();
// getting all of the post data
$files = Input::file('images');
// Making counting of uploaded images
$file_count = count($files);
// start count how many uploaded
$uploadcount = 0;
foreach($files as $file) {
  $rules = array('file' => 'required'); //'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'
  $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
  if($validator->passes()){
    $destinationPath = 'uploads';
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    $uploadcount ++;
    $multiupload->fileimage = $filename;
    $multiupload->save();
  }
}
if($uploadcount == $file_count){
  Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully'); 
  return Redirect::to('/');
} 
else {
  return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

}

After upload all images successfully move to 'Uploads' folder but, in database it store only one image name. So how to store all images name in database?
Please help me and thanks you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @edrzej.kurylo said

You have to add the below line to inside of `foreach($files as $file) {`

```
$multiupload = new Multiupload();
```

Because you are reusing the same Multiupload function again and again. You have to re initialize the Model for every time the loop runs.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are reusing the same Multiupload instance in your loop and just overwriting the saved name with the name of next file. You should be creating a new Multiupload instance for every file that gets uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your $multiupload = new Multiupload(); into the foreach loop.

```
foreach($files as $file) {
   $multiupload = new Multiupload();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use for loop in this manner:

```
if($request->hasFile('images'){
    $files = $request->file('images');
    for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++){
        $img = new SampleImage();
        $name = rand().'.'.$files[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $files[$i]->move('uploads/samples/',$name);
        $img->image_name = $name;
        $img->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. Also, when you post code, indent it! Your code was unreadable before my edit. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).