# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() laravel-5.3

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

i have this on my Controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $images = $request->file('image');
    $file_count = count($images);
    $uploadcount = 0;
    $daily = new Report();

    foreach($images as $image) {    
    $daily = new Report();    
    $destination ='img/report';
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    storage::put('img/report/'.$filename,file_get_contents($request->file('image')->getRealPath()));        
    $daily->image = $filename;
    $uploadcount ++;        
    }
    $daily->author = $request->author;
    $daily->desc = $request->desc;
    // $daily->created_at = Carbon::now();
    $daily->save();
if($uploadcount == $file_count){ 
return redirect('/daily');
}else{
return redirect('/daily/create');
}
}
```

and the browser say : Call to a member function getRealPath() on array
i want to store multiple image to database.

this is my blade.php

```
<form action="/daily/create" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}">
    {{-- date --}}
    {!! Form::text('date', old('date', Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('d-m-Y')),['class'=>'form-control date-picker']) !!}
    {{-- penulis --}}
    <label for="author">Author :</label>
    <input  name="author" type="text" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
    {{-- textarea --}}
    <label for="desc">Description</label>
    <textarea name="desc" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    {{-- input image --}}
    <div class="file-field input-field">
  <div class="btn">
    <span>File</span>
    <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple>
  </div>
  <div class="file-path-wrapper">
    <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload one or more files">
  </div>
</div>
<center>
<input type="submit" class="btn">
</center>

    </form>
```

should i delete the '[]' on the 'blade' image input ?
and 'array' it on controller ? how i do that ?

Comment: Are you passing an array of `image` from the view?

Comment: $images is not an array, you can do dd($images) and see what data type it is

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi i dont know, i just read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468120/how-to-upload-multiple-images-and-store-their-name-in-database-with-laravel-5-1
and follow it then error :(

Comment: check if input image is something like this: <input type="file" name="image[ ]"  > input mùst have array format, check also if the form is mutipart to pass images to the controller

Comment: @michaeltintiuc i get null so the 'images' not array ?

Comment: Show your HTML form in your question.

Comment: @iCode i update the question help .... ;(

Comment: @michaeltintiuc helpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your following code in your controller:

```
storage::put('img/report/'.$filename,file_get_contents($request->file('image')->getRealPath()));
```

to

```
storage::put('img/report/'.$filename,file_get_contents($image->getRealPath()));
```

Comment: yesssss it work big thanks... but  just the last name of image store to database 
all image stored in folder, how i called all image if just 1 name of image stored in database ?

Comment: but just the last name of image store to database all image stored in folder, how i called all image if just 1 name of image stored in database

Comment: You have to save it each time in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: i add this on foreach and the hust the last name stored to database $daily->image = $filename;